# Why are some questions shown with a blue background?

Tags: discussion

As of today some questions show on the main page with a blue background. Why?

- It's not questions I've viewed.
- It's not questions I've responded to.
- It's not questions where I commented on someone's answer.

So what is it?

Comment: Do you have any *favorite tags* selected?

Comment: No. I just checked and I've nothing selected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is highlighting questions with tags that are in your favorite tags.  If you haven't manually added any favorite tags, the system will detect when you have a certain level of activity in a tag and infer one for you.  If you manually add a favorite tag, the system will not infer tags for you.

You can customize your favorite (and ignored tags) in [your profile](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/2124/gef05?tab=prefs).  You can also customize these settings in the right sidebar of the homepage and the /questions listing.

So, if you would prefer not to have any questions highlighted, you can simply add a nonsense "tag" to your favorites.  Perhaps [unicorn](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unicorn)? (:

Comment: @Rebecca Yes, thanks - I wasn't aware of this inferring functionality, either.  (Of course, I had a few tags set as favorites, so I didn't notice.)

Comment: @gef just to be clear, you *do* have to visit a lot of questions with a specific tag for it to become an inferred favorite tag. So it is not coincidental, for the record. :)

Comment: @Jeff. No worries; makes sense.

Comment: @jeff How many is a lot?  It hasn't inferred any tags for me, nor do I have any specified manually.